# Retain persistent Wi-Fi connection on Raspberry Pi

Tags: wifi, linux, cron, wireless-adapter

I have a Raspberry Pi that I need it to remain connected to my WiFi constantly (at least as soon as the WiFI becomes available). In practice, however, I have noticed that when there are problems with the WiFi, it gets disconnected and it takes quite a lot of time to reconnect (e.g. 1 minute). Even worst, there are some rare occasions when the RPi after disconnecting, it does not try to reconnect back at all.

My question is, is there any CRON-driven (and lightweight hopefully) script that will force (at second granularity) the RPi since its very boot, to be trying to reconnect (in case it is not connected) to a specific WiFi AP?

I have `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` in `/etc/rc.local` but the problem remains.

My RPi is:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Comment: Add `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off` to `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: After adding it, I check whether it has been indeed applied with "iw wlan0 get power_save". I notice that indeed it has been applied cause I get "Power save: off". However, after a while when checking again, I get again "Power save: on".

Is there any way to make it permanent? And by default be deactivated?